# jQuery attrib using data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok, I'm confused on this portion, but i already follow the guidelines, and when i applied it, still placing the data attributes instead of the value to my hidden input.

Here's the HTML code

```
<div class="aside">
  <a href="#" class="user1" data-userid="1">User Name 1</a>
  <a href="#" class="user2" data-userid="2">User Name 2</a>
</div>
<form action="" method="post" class="form1">
  <input type="hidden" value="">
  <textarea name="msg" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
</form>
```

While here's the short jQuery

```
$(".aside").find("a").on("click", function(){
  $(this).offsetParent().find(".form1 input").attr('data-userid', $('input').attr('value'));
});
```

I would like to get the value of the UserID data and pass it to my hidden input.
I feel I am in there, but still giving me the wrong attr instead of the value. A small explanation would appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".aside a").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var userID = $(this).data('userid');
    $('.form1 input[type="hidden"]').val(userId);
});
```

Comment: Hi Sir, thanks for the answer, however i figured out that your statement created another data-userid inside the hidden input...

Comment: @user852916 I'm not sure what you mean. Your question states that you are trying to set the value of the hidden input with the data property of the clicked a element.

Comment: Oh, my bad... i got it now. i've checked the source code inside the JSFiddle over my codes.. anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
 $('.aside a').click(function(e){
      $('input[type=hidden]').val($(this).data('userid'));
      e.preventDefault();
 });
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/7kJ33/)**

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the userid of the clicked `a`

```
$(".aside a").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.aside').next().find("input").attr('data-userid', $(this).data('userid'));
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jSDDL/)

Also have do you want to set the attribute or the hidden element's value

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(".aside").find("a").on("click", function(e){

  e.preventDefault();
  $("input").val($(this).attr('data-userid'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use `.data()`:

```
 $(this).data('userid'):
```

**Click code:**

```
  $(".aside").find("a").on("click", function(){
 $(this).offsetParent().find(".form1 input").attr('data-userid', $('input').attr('value'));
 $("#form1 input").val($(this).data('userid'));
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HwexS/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".aside").find("a").on("click", function(){
  $(".form1 input").attr('value',$(this).attr('data-userid'));
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cp5y6/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".aside a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var userID = $(this).data('userid');
    $('.form1 input[type="hidden"]').val(userId);
});
```

As you don't load any DOM elements dynamically that would be more convenient to use jQuery's click() function instead of on('click') because it is more readable and easy to debug.

Comment: Improve your answer by adding an explanation as to why this would help the OP

Comment: The answer is pretty much the same to Rory's however click() would work better than on('click') in this situation.